# Why is child process running code of its parent and how to prevent it?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, signals

I have a main class which spawns a number of child processes which are subclasses of multiprocessing.Process and then enters an infinite loop to wait until the process is interrupted by a signal.

It's started from a __main__.py file which looks like this:

```
from module a import A
import signal
a = A()

def graceful_exit(signal=None, frame=None):
    a.stop()

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, graceful_exit)

try:
    write_pidfile(pid)
    a.start()
finally:
    graceful_exit()
```

The startup process of the main class looks like this:

```
def start(self):
    # some initialization
    for i in range(self.num_workers):
        worker = Worker()
        self.workers.append(worker)
        worker.start()
    for w in self.workers:
        w.join()
```

The worker doesn't do anything special, it just runs some mindless work in an infinite loop.

Then there is the stop method:

```
def stop(self):
    log.info('waiting for workers to finish')
    for w in self.workers:
        w.terminate()
```

Now the problem is that whenever the main process receives a signal (SIGTERM or SIGINT) I get the following output:

```
2016-04-26 12:53:04,651 MainProcess gateway INFO     waiting for workers to finish
2016-04-26 12:53:04,653 Worker-1   gateway INFO     waiting for workers to finish
2016-04-26 12:53:04,654 Worker-1   gateway INFO     waiting for workers to finish
```

And consequently:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'terminate'
```

Can someone explain to me why the child process is trying to run the code of the parent and how I can catch an appropriate signal in the main process and clean up the worker processes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Unix (I assuming you're such OS) the creation of a new process is implemented via forking the currently running one.

The newly created process (more simply child) will inherit all the parent's file descriptors and signal handlers.

This means that in your example, both parent and child processes will deal in the same way with a delivered SIGTERM signal.

In several implementations, [signals will be delivered to process groups](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html#tag_03_177_08) thus resulting in both processes receiving the same signal.

To solve your specific problem, just install the signal handler in the parent process **after** you spawned the child one.